# SonarQube 7.7 stopped working for XCode 12

Tags: objective-c, swift, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, xcode12

I'm using SonarQube 7.7.0.23042, SonarCFamily 6.1, SonarSwift 4.1 for XCode project with Swift and Objective-C code, it has been working from the beginning until I upgraded to XCode 12.

> ERROR: String is not parsed, (file FILENAME.swift, line LINE_NUMBER):

Most of the errors seem to be whenever I have:

```
guard let self = self
```

Or complicate closure syntax. After several of these errors the output has:

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36    java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: exit code != 0
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.analyzer.AnalysisExecutor.submit(AnalysisExecutor.java:47)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.plugin.CFamilySensor.process(CFamilySensor.java:310)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.plugin.CFamilySensor.process(CFamilySensor.java:279)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.plugin.CFamilySensor.execute(CFamilySensor.java:198)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:62)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:359)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:354)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:317)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:128)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:137)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: exit code != 0
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.analyzer.Subprocess.execute(Subprocess.java:54)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.analyzer.Subprocess.execute(Subprocess.java:25)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.plugin.CFamilySensor.lambda$process$4(CFamilySensor.java:323)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at com.sonar.cpp.analyzer.AnalysisExecutor.lambda$submit$0(AnalysisExecutor.java:53)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> 25-Sep-2020 16:55:36            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Since the version of SQ is quite old, I’m thinking if I should upgrade to a newer version, at least the next LTS version. Just for the sake of understanding the root cause, what can it be? Could it be XCode 12 has changed test result format, or build wrapper can no longer extract necessary information from build?

Comment: We are as perplexed as you are with XC12. Just for clarity. Is this XC 12.0 or 12.0.1?  If you are still on 12 try 12.0.1 maybe. Also what is your target iOS?

Comment: Thanks @skaak I think it's 12, I'll try 12.0.1, I'm not sure if it makes any difference though; And, how does target iOS (iOS 10) matter? Do you have similar problem?

Comment: 12 has been one uphill battle. I think 12.0.1 fixes some issues but too early to tell. 10!!! Ooooh that is old, but yes I also have a iOS 10 target somewhere but not really worked on that since 12 so don't know yet. What is funny though is that your error looks like a Java stack trace ... also the length and suddenness of it gives the appearance of IDE or compiler trouble.

Comment: btw, noticing all that Java ... Yes we have a new Xcode but Java has also been through a lot of changes recently. That problem you are seeing, maybe it is because of Java changes?

Comment: Thanks @skaak I guess the scanner itself is written in Java? The error "String is not parsed" feels like it cannot read the test coverage result generated by XCode which makes me think if XCode 12 has a different format for test coverage report.

Comment: @skaak let to let you know, there's a ticket for a very similar problem: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/swift-analyzer-error-on-new-swift-4-2-syntax/6022 which was resolved in SwiftSonar 4.2 and I'm using 4.1 at the moment, so I'll try upgrading at least SwiftSonar to 4.2 and see.

Comment: thanks - that ticket you mention looks like your problem! SQ is just used to analyze your code right? So it should be fairly safe to upgrade and not a disaster if the upgrade fails.